# How to make input text border with CSS when it's OnFocus

Tags: html, css

it's possible to make it like this when you onfocus (onclick) on the input text. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

You can make use of [outline](http://caniuse.com/#search=outline) and [:focus](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-focus),  these are compatible with major browsers.

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" class="inp" />
<br>
<input type="text" class="inp" />
```

#### CSS

```
.inp{
    border:solid 2px gray;    
    margin: 20px 5px;
    outline:solid 10px silver;
}
.inp:focus{
    outline:solid 10px red;
}
```

#### [Preview on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/Z2z7C/)

Comment: Is it possible to make different sizes for top-bottom-left-right borders? I've read that you cannot use outline for this purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
input:focus
{
    background-color:blue;//*
}
```

***this is just a example to change the background color.Do any thing that u desire here**

Take look at complete example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_focus).

Comment: This add a color in a box. I need color out of the box. I have a div box where I have 2 input text fields. So when you click on input field the color should spreads like on the picture.

Comment: You might have to use javascript for that. I will edit my answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the input with an anchor tag, and set it to change background-color `onfocus`:

`<a class='focused'><input /></a>`

with CSS:

`.focused:hover{
  background-color:blue;
}`

or, if you want it to change when the `input` is active, you need to use javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to wrap each input in a div and give that div a background color when it has focus using JavaScript. Here's a version in jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('focus', function() {
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'blue');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this CSS trick can be used rarely in real cases, but it is funny, that we can make this effect with box-shadows.

http://jsfiddle.net/XSpwg/

HTML:

```
<div>
<form>
   <input></input>
   <input></input>
   <input></input>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
}

input {
    margin: 2em 0.5em;
    display: block;
    border: solid 2px lightblue;
    outline: none;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

input:focus {
    box-shadow: 180px 227px 0 200px lightgrey,
                180px 195px 0 200px blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pseudo-class selector for various effects.

There are **two possible methods** using CSS

**Method 1** --> if you need both hover and on focus effect then use border styling for the `<input>` element

here is a typical HTML and CSS for method 1, --> [Jsfiddle view](http://jsfiddle.net/TKLAT/)

HTML

```
<form class="form-style">
    <input class="input-style" type="text" name="some-name">
    <input class="input-style" type="text" name="some-name">
</form>
```

CSS

```
.form-style
{
    width: 250px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    display:block;
}
.input-style
{
    width:200px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    line-height: 2;
    border-width: 20px 25px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #d6d6d6;
    display: block;

}
input.input-style:focus, input.input-style:hover
{
    border-color: #3399FF;
}
```

**Method 2** -> if you need just a hover effect then enclose the `<input>` element in a `<div>` and add `:hover` effect to it, or you can use the method 1 `:hover` and remove the `:focus` selector

here is a typical HTML and CSS for method 2, --> [Jsfiddle view](http://jsfiddle.net/9aCRb/)

HTML

```
<form class="form-style">
    <div class="input-style">
        <input type="text" name="some-name">
    </div>
    <div class="input-style">
        <input type="text" name="some-name">
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.form-style
{
    width:250px;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
}
.input-style
{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    padding:20px 25px 20px 25px;
    display: block;

}

.input-style input
{
    width:inherit;
    line-height: 2;
    display: block;
}
.input-style:hover
{
    background-color: #3399FF;
}
```

**My advice -> just use on focus effect, because on hover will highlight the `<input>` on which the mouse is over even if you you are typing (on focus) in another `<input`>**